# bad operand types for binary operator '>' in JAVA

Tags: java

I get this error on my program and can't figure it out.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) 

    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    boolean isOrdered;
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(z);
    asc = x<y<z;
    dec = x>y>z;
      If (asc || dec);
            isOrdered = true;
            System.out.println(isOrdered);  
            Else 
 isOrdered = false;
 System.out.println(isOrdered);
```

Comment: Is this really JAVA Code ? (It doesn't look like , for me) [The syntax is wrong and even note that Java is case-sensitive]

Comment: i just started learning java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do this in java:

```
asc = x<y<z;
dec = x>y>z;
```

< and > accept only two operands.

instead, you should use:

```
boolean asc = x<y && y<z;
boolean dec = x>y && y>z;
```

EDIT: adding the correct if-else syntax:

```
  if (asc || dec) {
        isOrdered = true;
        System.out.println(isOrdered);  
  } else { 
        isOrdered = false; 
        System.out.println(isOrdered);
  }
```

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable asc
  location: class Ordered

Comment: I just copied it from your original code, you don't declare asc and dec before that segment? if not, add `boolean` before both rows. also - take a look at the comments you got on your questions, there are some other java syntax errors in your code

Comment: i have a problem with the ''else'' now cannot be used without ''if'' but i wrote if

Comment: take a look at my last edit - your if-else statement was wrong (use {} and not ; and should have it lowercase)

Comment: didn't knew it was case sensitive. Thank you for the help it worked!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
asc = x<y<z;
dec = x>y>z;
```

to

```
asc = (x < y && y < z);
desc = (x > y && y > z);
```

check the case of `if` and `else`, use `{}` for case and loops

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable asc
  location: class Ordered
the same for des